# How can I add space to <li> elements at the top and bottom with CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="admin_btn" href="/adminFormat" style="width:100px;">Format</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_btn" href="/adminStatus" style="width:100px;">Status</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_btn" href="/adminMembership" style="width:100px;">Membership</a></li>
</ul>
```

And

```
a.admin_btn {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.admin_btn:hover {
    background: #bbb;
    color: #000;
}
```

But when I use this on my web page, the buttons are too close together vertically, and the `<li>` circles show.

How can I space out the buttons and remove the `<li>` circles?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the circles:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
```

to add space, for example use:

```
li { margin-bottom: 16px }
```

Comment: @JudyJ You can show your appreciation by clicking the check mark to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the dots:

```
li.leaf, li.collapsed, li.expanded {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

And for the space:

```
li {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

You can replace `10px` with any value you want to get the desired space.